# Word for something that is true only at a specific period in time

Tags: word-request, legalese

I am writing a paper about fair division. When we divide, say, a piece of land among us, the division may be fair in the time of division, but may seem unfair at a later time, for example, if oil is found in one of the land-plots.

I am looking for a single word (a noun) that emphasizes the fact that a division is fair only in a specific point in time. Using Google translate, I found "momentariness", "instantaneity", "temporariness", but, I don't which of these words, if any, fits the context.

An example paragraph: "Our third assumption is _____________. This means that, when we check the fairness of a certain division procedure, we only check that the division is fair at the time it is made. We do not require that it remains fair forever."

Comment: None of those words are particularly common and might sound odd depending on the context. I think it would help if you provided an example sentence.

Comment: *transient*? *ephemeral*? - looking at the title of the question though.

Comment: Though many words could be used there, I personally like a simple word such as *temporal*, in a sense that "the assumption is temporal" means the division is fair as long as it is fair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an example sentence were provided, looking for an answer would be easier, but I like the word "transience". The adjective 'transient' related to it may be used in a construction like "transient nature of", the word nature being the core noun there:

> "The transient nature of any value fixed to a piece of land makes it impossible to make sure that any division scheme fair at the moment would still be be fair after some time has passed".

There are [synonyms](http://thesaurus.com/browse/transience) for *transience* like ephemerality, fugacity, but they belong more to the [belles-lettres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belles-lettres) style of writing.

Related words: unreliability, unpredictability, inconstancy, impermanence. These may be 'adjectivized' and used in constructions like "unreliable nature/character of...".

Comment: Thanks. I added an example paragraph. I think "impermanence" is the best fit. What do you think?

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi: Looks fine to me, but mind that I'm not a native speaker.

Answer (score 1):

*"Our third assumption is contemporary."*

Contemporary indicates that something is correct within a given time-frame and this suits your example.

It is sometimes used for an implicit current time-frame to indicate that something is modern but as your example goes on to explain the time-frame this misunderstanding would not occur.

Comment: This is an adjective... maybe you meant "contemporariness" or something like this?

Comment: Contemporary actually refers to something in a current context, which is not what you are trying to convey. I think another word choice would be preferable.